# How to duplicate a table with keys & other structure features retained in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, key

How to duplicate a table with keys & other structure features retained? including primary key, foreign keys, and indexes.

Can this be done with a single MySQL query?

I'm using "create table newtable as select..." but this method makes all keys & indexes lost.

Comment: You can turn indexes on after creating table using "ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX ...". This way is good, because insertion in new table will be faster without indexes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

duplicating a table from another table (with indexing and structure)cannot be done with a single query
you will need need 2 queries.

1) To create Duplicate table.

`CREATE TABLE Table2 LIKE Table1;`

This will create an exact copy of the table.

2) Fill in the Duplicate table with values from original table.

`INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT * from Table1;`

will fill Table2 with all the records fom Table1

Answer (score 7):

you can do it in this query

```
CREATE TABLE a LIKE b
```

after you can insert

```
INSERT INTO a SELECT * FROM b
```

read more information in this [article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/copy-table-mysql-create-table-like/)

Answer (score 0):

Following query creates and duplicates data.

`CREATE TABLE table2 SELECT * FROM table1`